# Optimizing a Gallery and its Adapter

Tags: android, caching, optimization, gallery, adapter

I have a Gallery.  This Gallery has a lot going on in it and it is slowing down the scrolling effect substantially.  Does anyone have any idea as to how to optimize something like this?

The essence of my question is this: How can I make layouts that zip substantially faster than their standard android implementations.  Renderscript?  NDK?  Flash layouts?

Keep in mind I am already caching my views.  I know this is a very general question so any and all input is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you do use the recycledview in your adapter?

Comment: How complex are your items? I am wondering whats the reason for the sluggishness. You shouldn't be doing much inside the adapter, apart from setting the views.

Comment: It's the gallery itself, actually, that contains many view that are removed and then added.  Also the Gallery itself undergoes a transform (many) when the user moves it.  There are also animations.  Putting it together, you can see it get slower bit by bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here is what I found from watching just the first several minutes of this video: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9S5EO7CLjo

I am building my app on 3.1.  In the application tag of the Manifest, add the following as an attribute: android:hardwareAccelerated="true".  The difference in UI performance is amazing.  Thumbs up to Google for this addition to the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Quite often a sluggish UI is the result of doing a lot of work on the UI thread. I suppose you could double check whether this is the case and consider abstracting non-UI related logic into one or more different theads. E.g. you probably want to avoid fetching large amounts of resources from the SD card or a database on the UI thread. Doing such actions in seperate thread might improve responsiveness, although results will obviously depend on the particulars of your app.